# How do I organise 5 items evenly in a row with material-ui's grid system?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The grid system is 12, how can I evenly put 5 items in a row? 2.4 doesn't work... Thanks in advance :)

my code:

```
    <Grid container spacing={10}>
        {data.map(item => (
          <Grid item xs={12} md={2.4}>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "700", textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
              {item}
            </div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the Auto Layout section from the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#auto-layout) for an example of how to do this.

For your code, I believe the following should work:

```
<Grid container spacing={10}>
  {data.map(item => (
    <Grid item xs={12} md>  // should also add a "key" prop here
      <div style={{ fontWeight: "700", textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        {item}
      </div>
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```

Comment: this didn't work as requested in the title of the question

Answer (score 10):

You can try adding `<Grid lg={12/5}></Grid.` this case works if you want to show 5 elements in one row

Comment: this is a simple perfect answer! and it works perfectly as expected

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Grid container` flex direct to `raw` and give each item `xs={2}` for all of them to fit, also you can add some spacing and center elements to container itself. In case you want each item be bigger then 2, consider wrap the row in a ScrollY custom component

---

```
   <Grid container spacing={1} direction="row"  justify="center"  alignItems="center" >
    {data.map(item => (
      <Grid item xs={2}}>
        <div style={{ fontWeight: "700", textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
          {item}
        </div>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>



// optional ScrollY wrapper, use like <ScrollY> {data.map ...}</ScrollY>

const ScrollY = (props) => 
  <div style={{overflowX:'hidden', overflowY: 'scroll',dispaly:'none', height: '80%'}}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
```